# Deleting hyperlinks in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, href

I am using Data List and have a column type string (numbers separated by semicolon). On the Item bound side I am separating it with semicolon and adding hyperlink to each those numbers. Now I wanted to provide a functionality where a client can remove the hyperlink and I am not sure how can I achieve it . I have two options:

1. Providing a button on the client side on the click event of hyperlink, where it says, Open or delete the link and on the server side I delete it from database.
2. simple cross (x) next to all numbers and on click delete it from database .

Although I don't get how to attach button on the server side to each of those numbers and/or other ways to provide this functionality.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a javascript solution would work. You would need to create an AJAX request that deletes the record from the database then in the callback method you remove the link.

Comment: and how can I attach the buttons next / on to the hyperlink in the item bound event on server side ?

Comment: You could create an AJAX GET request that hits your target page and returns a list of the numbers/ids. Then you could create the hyperlinks using javascript and add them to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around using this : 
I am using Update panel so I added my code in both $document.ready() as well as   :
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest();

https://forums.asp.net/t/2121543.aspx?How+to+Delete+the+Hyperlink+on+the+Client+Side+